# How to assign realm result object to variable with. a class type

Tags: swift, realm

Is there any way to assign realm result object to variable with a class type: I have var movies: Results! in one view controller and variable  var currentMovie : Movie? in another and I'm trying to pass it thru prepare for segue method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destVc = segue.destination as? PlaySelectedFavoritesViewController 
    destVc?.movies = movies[selectedRow]
}
```

But, that results in the following error.

> Error: Cannot assign value of type 'FavoriteMoviesModel' to type
>   'Movie?'

Here is class and struct

````
    class FavoriteMoviesModel: Object {
              @objc dynamic var title = ""
              @objc dynamic var poster_path = ""
              @objc dynamic var id = 0
          }

       ```
      Movie struct 
      ```


      struct Movie: Codable {
              let title: String?
              let poster_path: String?
              let id: Int?
              enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                  case title = "title"
                  case poster_path = "poster_path"
                  case id = "id"
              }
          }
````

Comment: Those 2 are different types. You can't assign one type to another, so create a function / initialiser to convert one to the other.

Comment: Results is an object that can hold many movies and is a live updating object that reflects results of sorting and filtering (or all objects of a certain class). A movie is a single object that doesn't do that.  Are you wanting to get a single movie from your Results and pass that particular movie to another viewController? If so, then `let thisMovie = realm.objects(Movie.self).filter("title == 'Airplane'").first` will do that. It's not safe to unwrap optionals like that but you should get the idea.